# Convert comma separated values to rows using AWK but starting from second column

Tags: csv, awk

I am working on below sample.txt file to convert the columns to rows but starting from second column.

```
$ cat sample.txt
ENGLISH,UK,USA,CA,SA
HINDI,IN,NEP
SPANISH,MEX,SPAIN,AG
FRENCH,FR,CA
```

Looking for following output.

```
1,ENGLISH,UK
2,ENGLISH,USA
3,ENGLISH,CA
4,ENGLISH,SA
1,HINDI,IN
2,HINDI,NEP
1,SPANISH,MEX
2,SPANISH,SPAIN
3,SPANISH,AG
1,FRENCH,FR
2,FRENCH,CA
```

This is what I could achieve so far..

```
$ cat sample.txt | awk -F',' '{out=$1; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){out=(i-1)" "$1" "$i}; print out}'
4 ENGLISH SA
2 HINDI NEP
3 SPANISH AG
2 FRENCH CA
```

Comment: Clear sample input and expected output and a solid attempt at a solution. Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) print i-1, $1, $i}' sample.txt
1,ENGLISH,UK
2,ENGLISH,USA
3,ENGLISH,CA
4,ENGLISH,SA
1,HINDI,IN
2,HINDI,NEP
1,SPANISH,MEX
2,SPANISH,SPAIN
3,SPANISH,AG
1,FRENCH,FR
2,FRENCH,CA
```

Mainly you were just overwriting "out" every iteration through the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Move the `print` statement inside `for` loop. Your code should look like below:

```
$ cat sample.txt | awk -F',' '{out=$1; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){out=(i-1)","$1","$i; print out;}}'
```

Output:

```
1,ENGLISH,UK
2,ENGLISH,USA
3,ENGLISH,CA
4,ENGLISH,SA
1,HINDI,IN
2,HINDI,NEP
1,SPANISH,MEX
2,SPANISH,SPAIN
3,SPANISH,AG
1,FRENCH,FR
2,FRENCH,CA
```

Comment: This removes commas in the output (`OFS` not set), and the `cat` is useless, and then you have the same solution as Ed ;)